# Inheriting Sitecore Roles

Tags: security, role-management

I have a role "Editor" which is having certain permissions and don't have read access to Sitecore/Social item.

Now i need to create a new role "Approver" which is having same access as Editor but with additional Read and Write access to Sitecore/Social Item.

I tried by making Approver as member of Editor and then gave additional access to Approver. But this is not working.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Deny` access right cannot be overwritten by any allow rule.

What you need to do is to:

- remove that `Deny` read access for `Editor` role
- make your `Approver` role a member of `Editor` role
- disable inheritance of access rights for that item for your `Editor` role
- and for your `Approver` role you need to assign `Read` and `Write` back

More information can be found in https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/security_and_administration/access_rights/the_inheritance_access_right